# How to make edits to a gem and have that take affect on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem to which I want to make a few edits. 
I have opened the gem using

```
bundle open gem_name
```

Made the edits and they work fine on development. 
What do I need to do in order to make the changes take affect on heroku. 
There is nothing to commit locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local gem is modified, but during deployment the one on github gets installed.
What you could do is to find the gem project on github, and fork it.
Then you can apply all your custom mods and commit into your gem repo.
Once you're done, remember to point to the right repo in your Gemfile:

```
gem your_gem, , :git => "https://github.com/your_user_name/your_gem.git"
```

Comment: As a shortcut, you can say `:github => 'your_user_name/your_gem'`, though this will use the `git` protocol rather than `https`.

Answer (score 1):

You can vendorize the gem like this:-

```
gem unpack my_private_gem --target vendor/gems
```

and then in your Gemfile

```
gem 'my_private_gem', :path => "vendor/gems/my_private_gem-VERSION"
```